# How Can We Have A SCROLLABLE GridView With Fixed Header?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, gridview, header, scrollable

How Can We Have A SCROLLABLE GridView With Fixed Header???(in vs 2008 - asp.net with c#)

Fixed Header is my problem!

i test many ways for doing that and see some live demos / but they did not work.

can u show me a simple way 4 doing that with an example?

Comment: Why ways did you try?  CSS?  Wrapping the GridView in a Panel/div?

Comment: i tried div and panel and scrollbar is working perfectly...But my Problem Is About Fixed Header... when u scroll the gridview so header disappears , but i do not want it. how can i fix that with css?

Comment: is there any idea about fixed header?

Answer (score 1):

two tables, one for header and one for content. only problem is that u need to set specific widths for each column.

```
<style>
    .tbl th { border: 1px solid black; background:#DDD; }
    .tbl td { border: 1px solid black; border-top:none }
    .scroll { height:80px; overflow-y:auto }
</style>

<table class="tbl">
    <colgroup>
        <col style="width:100px" />
        <col style="width:150px" />
    </colgroup>
    <tr>
        <th>header1</th>
        <th>header2</th>
    </tr>
 </table>

<div class="scroll">
    <table class="tbl">
        <colgroup>
            <!-- same as before -->
            <col style="width:100px" />
            <col style="width:150px" />
        </colgroup>
        <tr><td>....</td><td>...</td></tr>
        <tr><td>....</td><td>...</td></tr>
        <tr><td>....</td><td>...</td></tr>
        <tr><td>....</td><td>...</td></tr>
        <tr><td>....</td><td>...</td></tr>
        <tr><td>....</td><td>...</td></tr>
        <tr><td>....</td><td>...</td></tr>
        <tr><td>....</td><td>...</td></tr>
        <tr><td>....</td><td>...</td></tr>
    </table>
<div>
​
```

Answer (score 0):

This blog post might help you:

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=255&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

He has found a way to create fixed gridview headers and footers using a bit of jQuery. I haven't tried this myself, but judging by the comments, it works for many people.

Comment: hi my dear friend / i saw your link / but i could not find scroll bar in it's project...!

Answer (score 0):

Following link contains jquery and gridview sorting with fixed headers

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Scrollable-GridView-with-Fixed-Headers-and-Client-Side-Sorting-using-jQuery-in-ASP.Net.aspx