# Tablesorter scroller not working as expected

Tags: tablesorter

This is a follow-up question on this question:
[ASP.NET Gridview tablesorter with fixed header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45239410/asp-net-gridview-tablesorter-with-fixed-header)

My problem is that I'm trying to use the tablesorter plugin to sort a table and also make the table scrollable. The sorting part works great, but I haven't managed to enable the scroll.

The documentation is not very clear if you've never used the plugin before. There is no video tutorial available. I could only find a tutorial for the sorting part. What basic steps do I need to do to enable the scroller?

I have made a new asp.net web form app. It's a brand new clean project. I added a simple table with thead and tbody. I added the columns and rows. The table has the `class="tablesorter"`. I have referenced the following external files:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/tablesorter.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.tablesorter-widgets.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/widgets/widget-scroller.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function (){
        $("table").tablesorter({
            widgets: ['scroller'],
            widgetOptions: {
                scroller_height: 300,
                scroller_barWidth: 17,
                scroller_jumpToHeader: true}
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have added the functions just like in the documentation. It's not working. I am using tablesorter version 2.28.15

### Update

While playing around with the code, I removed all the css, and the only code I am using aside from the referencing scripts, is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $("table").tablesorter({
            theme: 'dark',
            headerTemplate: '{content} {icon}',
            widgets: ['uitheme', 'scroller'],
            widgetOptions: {
                scroller_upAfterSort: true,
                scroller_jumpToHeader: true,
                scroller_height: 300,
                scroller_barWidth: 17
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

When I click on one of the table columns, it renders another header on top of the first one. It renders a scroll slider on the right side and it changes the height of the table to 300.

This is great! It means it works, but why doesn't it render the slider from the beginning and only works when I click on the table header? Also, this happens every time I click on the table header. So if I click 5 times, I will have 5 table headers and 5 sliders.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Hi! I set up [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/ft3qyjns/9/) with some basic settings and I am not able to reproduce the issue you're describing. Would you please modify the demo to show the problem?

Comment: This is what it looks like: https://youtu.be/4U32isSg928 ...I'm only using the regular function where i specify scroller in the widget. The css is exactly like the one you have in the demo.

Comment: This is the asp project. Maybe it helps clear up my error. https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwlWg0JEosuNbE5abW1JTFI4TGs